# Get Access token form OneLogin using the PKCE .net core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm Trying to get the access token form OneLogin using the Authorization Code with PKCE. I'm able to go through step1 for PKCe and getting the authorization code back from OneLogin. But when i try to get the token using the authorization code sent by one login i keep getting 400 bad request error. I'm not sure what is wrong. I followed the info provided by oneLogin website to all required parameters in the request for Step 2. below the code i'm using. I will appreciate if some one can help on this.

public async Task GetAccessToken(string redirecturl, string authCode)
{
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

```
        var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        

        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            grant_type = "authorization_code",
            code = authCode, ---The code returned from OneLogin in step 1
            client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX386d707215718",
            redirect_uri=redirecturl,--The redirect URL registered in onelogin account
            code_verifier=GetCacheEntry(CodeKey)-- the code verifier used in step one
        });
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://MySubdomain.onelogin.com/oidc/2/token"),
            Content = new StringContent(body)

        };
        req.Content.Headers.ContentType= new MediaTypeHeaderValue(@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var responseBody =await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthTokenResponse>(responseBody);
            memoryCache.Remove(CodeKey);
            return Ok(json);
        }
        
        return BadRequest(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're sending the body as a json content, although you've correctly specified the Content Type as x-www-form-urlencoded.

Here's how I create the body and send the request

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                { "code", code },
                { "code_verifier", AuthCodeParticipantDetail.CodeVerifier},
                { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
                { "redirect_uri", AuthCodeParticipantDetail.CallBackUrl},
                {"client_id", AuthCodeParticipantDetail.ClientId}
            };

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));

            var tokens = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Tokens>();
```